# My double function is not working correctly

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Application
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            public int times2(number)
            {
                result = number * 2;
                {
                    return result;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function that doubles a int, I get multiple errors when trying this code in Xarmin studio.

Comment: This seems like a pointless function even if thinking about readability...either way, all you need is `return number * 2;` But, you should first figure out how to write c# code as there are SOOO many syntax errors there

Comment: Read a tutorial about console applications in C#. You should make difference between methods and classes. You can't have nested methods. You can write in google basics about programing C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the data types. The right code is:

```
using System;
namespace Application
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public int times2 (int number)
        {
           return number * number;
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            times2(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed unreachable code return 0

Comment: And now times2 is badly named. :)

Comment: well you fixed the problems I saw, wasn't me who downvoted you though